# How to create a local elasticsearch cluster on my mac

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, firewall

I have a strange problem when trying to setup a local running elasticsaerch cluster. I have tried a lot of settings with the bind.host and the auto discovery but did not succeed. The strange thing is if I have my wireless connection connected to a network the two nodes do not see each other. If I switch it of I do not have a problem. Following is the configuration of one node that works without a wireless adapter connected.

Does anyone have a clue what to try to make my cluster work?

```
cluster.name: localcluster
node.name: two

index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0

network.host: _lo0:ipv4_

zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
```

Comment: Please let people know what version of OS X you are running. I suspect it's a firewall issue.

Comment: osx mavericks, have a firewall running called ice floor, but should not work on local interfaces. In the end I made a stupid mistake in the configuration, check the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `discovery.` in the zen discovery settings. Try these settings:

```
cluster.name: "localcluster"
network.host: _lo0:ipv4_
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300","127.0.0.1:9301","127.0.0.1:9302"]
```

Comment: I made some changes to make the configuration as easy a possible. This is working for me. No idea why I missed this but with the discovery. added it works.

Comment: I added several ports there for the reason. With your edits restarting first node in the cluster (one that listens on port 9200) will cause it not to join existing cluster.

Comment: Sorry imotov, you are right, you need the servers and the ports.